# How do you make .env file be read in Nuxt3 Production environment when using shared code

Tags: nuxt3, .env

I have a folder structure like this

[image: Image showing relationship between main and shared project folders]

'MagicTools' is a Nuxt3 project I'm working on.
'Common' is a folder containing code that will be common to all future Nuxt3 projects I'll build.
So, I simply write code like this in 'MagicTools':
import Log from "../Common/Log";
Log.setupLogger();
In the 'setupLogger' method, I have this
[image: Image showing the code in the setupLogger method]

My .env file (In MagicTools) contains the LOGS_DIR key and value.
It works perfectly well when I use 'npm run dev' (Development environment). I see my logs with every request.
But when I run 'npm run build' and 'nodemon .output/server/index.mjs' (Production environment), I get this error
[image: Image showing the error messages I get in production]
Is there a way to fix this issue?
I never had this issue when I used Nuxt2.
I don't want to go back to Nuxt2 because whenever I ran 'npm i', there would be at least 12 critical vulnerabilities that simply could not be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.
I went over to Nuxt3's official website concerning .env files https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/env
It says that the values in the .env files are not available when you run it in prod.
So, I installed dotenv and fixed it myself.

Comment: How exactly did you fix it? Can you share your solution please?

Comment: Oh. I ran 'npm install dotenv --save' and then put this in my startup code 'require('dotenv').config()'